# Add a new row between old table rows in Matlab appdesigner

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

After some research, I still can't find the solution for my problem. I have a table that it's filled with info from user, when a button is pushed. The idea is that once new information is inserted and the "add" button pushed, a new row is created on the table. For instance:

1. Start with a table of 5 rows
2. The user places the cursor at the third row (selected)
3. The user clicks on add new row button
4. A new row is added at row #3 and the old third row is now row #4

Does any of you have a suggestion?

Comment: Hi, you may want to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make your problem clear and show that you have put effort in asking this question

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Create a property in your UIFigure called `CurrentRow`.

```
properties (Access = private)
    CurrentRow % Last row selected in UITable
end
```

Whenever the user clicks on a cell in the table, the `UITableCellSelection` event is fired and you can set the `CurrentRow` property to be the selected row.

```
% Cell selection callback: UITable
function UITableCellSelection(app, event)
    app.CurrentRow = event.Indices(1);
end
```

Next the user clicks the "new row button" and we use the `ButtonPushed` event to insert the new row.

```
% Button pushed function: Button
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
    insertedRow = [1 2 3 4];
    temp = [app.UITable.Data(1:app.CurrentRow-1,:);insertedRow;app.UITable.Data(app.CurrentRow:end,:)];
    app.UITable.Data = temp;
end
```

Obviously, you will get the new row values from some other control on your form, whereas I've just assigned hard-coded values as an example.